# How to switch virtual terminal under Virtualbox on OSX

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I just installed Ubuntu Jaunty as a guest OS in VirtualBox 3.1, running under OSX. My problem is that I can't switch from X to a virtual terminal, Host+F1 doesn't work (host key being "Left cmd").. Is there another key combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out... `fn + host key + Fx`